# Creating a Word List array that can be modified by adding and removing words

Tags: java

In this problem, I am attempting to begin with an array and add or remove words. My problem so far is adding words. I want to have an array `String[] {"",""}` and fill this up, and if a word is repeated, do nothing. So, add("computer"), add("again"), and add("computer") would result in `{"computer", "again"}` and give me count 3. I keep getting `{"computer", "computer", "again"}` remove("computer") would result in `{"again", "again"}` and give me count 1. Could on look at this code and help?

```
   public class WordList {
   public String[] words;
   int count;

  public WordList() {
    count = 0;
    words = new String[] {"",""};
   }
   public int addWord(String w) {
      WordList r = new WordList();
      int x = r.findWord(w);
      int y = words.length;
      if (x>-1) {
          return count;
      }
      else if (x==-1) {
          if (count < words.length) {
              words[count] = w;
          }

          else if (count == words.length) {
              String[] nwords = new String[words.length * 2];
              for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                  nwords[i] = words[i];
              }
              words = nwords;
              words[y] = w;

          }
          count++;
      }
      return count;
   }
   public void removeWord(String s) {
       WordList r = new WordList();
       int x = r.findWord(s);
       if (x == -1) {
           return;
       }
       if (x>-1) {
           for (int j=0;j<words.length;j++) {
               words[j] = words[j+1];
               count--;
           }
       }
       return;
   }
   public int findWord(String w) {
       for (int i =0;i<words.length; i++) {
           if (w.equals(words[i])) {
               return i;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }
   public boolean equals(WordList other) {
       if (words.length != other.count) {
           return false;
       } else {
           for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
               if (words[i] != other.words[i]) {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       }
       return true;
   }

   public String toString() {
       String s = "There are " + count + " word" + ((words.length == 1)?"":"s") + " in the word list:\n";
       for (String w : words) {
           s = s + w + "\n";
       }
       return s;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       WordList wl = new WordList();
       System.out.println(wl.addWord("computer"));
       System.out.println(wl.addWord("abacus"));
       System.out.println(wl.addWord("computer"));
       wl.removeWord("computer");
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use an ArrayList or some other List implementation instead of an array.

Comment: I believe a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) or a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is a more appropriate data structure for your needs than an array.

Comment: The problem specifically asks to work with static arrays. I am in a course that has not yet moved on to ArrayLists, so I'm trying to work it out the way they ask. The outputs of the first three main lines should be 1, 2, and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. Please consider Arraylist or Map.
Nevertheless i tried to keep changes to the minimal

```
public class WordList {
   public String[] words;
   int count;

  public WordList() {
    count = 0;
    words = new String[] {"",""};
   }
   public int addWord(String w) {
      //WordList r = new WordList();
      int x = findWord(w);
      int y = words.length;
      if (x>-1) {
          return count++;
      }
      else if (x==-1) {
          if (count < words.length) {
              words[count] = w;
          }
      else if (count == words.length) {
          String[] nwords = new String[words.length * 2];
          for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
              nwords[i] = words[i];
          }
          words = nwords;
          words[y] = w;

      }
      count++;
      }
      return count;
   }
   public void removeWord(String s) {
       //WordList r = new WordList();
       int x = findWord(s);
       if (x == -1) {
           return;
       }
       if (x>-1) {
           for (int j=0;j<words.length;j++) {
               if(words.length < j+1 && !words[j+1].isBlank()){
                   words[j] = words[j+1];
                }
           }
            count--;
       }
       return;
   }
   public int findWord(String w) {
       for (int i =0;i<words.length; i++) {
           if (w.equals(words[i])) {
               return i;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }
   public boolean equals(WordList other) {
       if (words.length != other.count) {
           return false;
       } else {
           for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
               if (words[i] != other.words[i]) {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       }
       return true;
   }

   public String toString() {
       String s = "There are " + count + " word" + ((words.length == 1)?"":"s") + " in the word list:\n";
       for (String w : words) {
           s = s + w + "\n";
       }
       return s;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       WordList wl = new WordList();
       System.out.println(wl.addWord("computer"));
       System.out.println(wl);
       System.out.println(wl.addWord("abacus"));
       System.out.println(wl);
       System.out.println(wl.addWord("computer"));
       System.out.println(wl);
       wl.removeWord("computer");
       System.out.println(wl);
  }
}
```

The severe ones are:
1. You are working on new instances of wordlist (r) when adding and removing which is absolutely wrong.
2. When removing word you have to check the length of word before going for j+1

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Set`, not an array.

That will reduce your code to:

```
class WordList {
    private Set<String> words;

    public WordList() {
        words = new HashSet<>();
    }
    public int addWord(String w) {
        words.add(w);
        return words.size();
    }
    public void removeWord(String s) {
        words.remove(s);
    }
    public boolean findWord(String w) {
        return words.contains(w);
    }
    public boolean equals(WordList other) {
        return this.words.equals(other.words);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "There are " + words.size() + " word" + ((words.size() == 1)?"":"s") + " in the word list:\n";
        for (String w : words) {
            s = s + w + "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordList wl = new WordList();
        System.out.println(wl.addWord("computer"));
        System.out.println(wl.addWord("abacus"));
        System.out.println(wl.addWord("computer"));
        wl.removeWord("computer");
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
1
2
2
```